# How to iterate using ngFor loop Map containing key as string and values as map iteration

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am new to angular 5 and trying to iterate the map containing another map  in typescript. 
How to iterate below this kind of map in angular
below is code for component:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  map = new Map<String, Map<String,String>>();
  map1 = new Map<String, String>();

  constructor() { 


  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.map1.set("sss","sss");
    this.map1.set("aaa","sss");
    this.map1.set("sass","sss");
    this.map1.set("xxx","sss");
    this.map1.set("ss","sss");


    this.map1.forEach((value: string, key: string) => {
      console.log(key, value);

    });


    this.map.set("yoyoy",this.map1);

  }



}
```

and its template html is :

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let recipient of map.keys()">
    {{recipient}}
   </li>


</ul>

<div>{{map.size}}</div>
```

[image: runtime error]

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2246

Comment: what is the solution i dont wanna convert my map to array

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ifebvj?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: if map = new Map<String, Map<String,String>>();
 how does it works

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jm8jgz?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 457, accepted):

**For Angular 6.1+** , you can use default pipe **[`keyvalue`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)** ( [**Do review and upvote also**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52532564/2349407) ) :

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let recipient of map | keyvalue">
        {{recipient.key}} --> {{recipient.value}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-map-keyvalue)**

---

**For the previous version :**

One simple solution to this is convert map to array : **[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)**

Component Side :

```
map = new Map<String, String>();

constructor(){
    this.map.set("sss","sss");
    this.map.set("aaa","sss");
    this.map.set("sass","sss");
    this.map.set("xxx","sss");
    this.map.set("ss","sss");
    this.map.forEach((value: string, key: string) => {
        console.log(key, value);
    });
}

getKeys(map){
    return Array.from(map.keys());
}
```

Template Side :

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let recipient of getKeys(map)">
    {{recipient}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-map-array-from)**

Comment: if map = new Map<String, Map<String,String>>(); how does it works?

Comment: @FerozSiddiqui, I have updated the answer , and I think that will work for any nested level.

Comment: we lost all Map feature if we convert it into Array finally. what is the benefit of Map then?

Comment: @pro.mean , we are converting just because we want to loop through it via angular template as it want some iterable to iterate. and you still have original object `map` available you can use that one to use all benefit of Map

Comment: I understand your point. but when we finally have to loop why we have used *Map*, simply can be done with the *Array*. I was looking for the iterator for Map.

Comment: @pro.mean , we have converted just to show that on template side , but you still have Map obaject that you can use in your component side. you can ask to OP `why he needed this kind of requirement` , he can explain you better :)

Comment: @VivekDoshi Using angular6.1 method I had an issue where I lost the MAP ordering, so I had to user getKeys method to keep the ordering

Comment: Works also for [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) data type

Comment: keyvalue pipe works great, even though Intellij IDEA says that the argument is not assignable to this type.

Comment: keyvalue pipe is removing the inserted order

Answer (score 78):

If you are using Angular 6.1 or later, the most convenient way is to use [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

```
   @Component({
      selector: 'keyvalue-pipe',
      template: `<span>
        <p>Object</p>
        <div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
          {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
        </div>
        <p>Map</p>
        <div *ngFor="let item of map | keyvalue">
          {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
        </div>
      </span>`
    })
    export class KeyValuePipeComponent {
      object: Record<number, string> = {2: 'foo', 1: 'bar'};
      map = new Map([[2, 'foo'], [1, 'bar']]);
    }
```

Comment: Hopefully people scroll and see this answer, because I was about to do a refactor until I had seen this out-of-the-box pipe available for my `map` type which takes care of using it with `*ngFor`

Comment: it seems, keyvalue does not keep initial sorting of map :-(, you need to add comparer function to fix that

Comment: This is true. And here is an issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31420

Comment: Wow! I had no idea there was a pipe to iterate a map in the template so easily. This is so helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a snippet to create your own pipe to retain the sorting of the Map keys: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31420#issuecomment-671138557

Answer (score 29):

**Edit**

For angular 6.1 and newer, use the [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) as suggested by Londeren.

**For angular 6.0 and older**

To make things easier, you can create a pipe.

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'getValues'})
export class GetValuesPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(map: Map<any, any>): any[] {
        let ret = [];

        map.forEach((val, key) => {
            ret.push({
                key: key,
                val: val
            });
        });

        return ret;
    }
}

 <li *ngFor="let recipient of map |getValues">
```

As it it pure, it will not be triggered on every change detection, but only if the reference to the `map` variable changes

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p1vqq1?file=app%2Fget-values.pipe.ts)

Comment: @Ryan Pipes are pure by default. If you add a console.log in the pipe, you'll see that it does not get call multiple times. But  component  method in the accepted solution does...

Answer (score 14):

This is because `map.keys()` returns an iterator. `*ngFor` can work with iterators, but the `map.keys()` will be called on every change detection cycle, thus producing a new reference to the array, resulting in the error you see. By the way, this is not always an *error* as you  would traditionally think of it; it may even not break any of your functionality, but suggests that you have a data model which seems to behave in an insane way - changing faster than the change detector checks its value.

If you do no want to convert the map to an array in your component, you may use the pipe suggested in the comments. There is no other workaround, as it seems.

P.S. This error will not be shown in the production mode, as it is more like a very strict warning, rather than an actual error, but still, this is not a good idea to leave it be.

Answer (score 5):

Angular’s `keyvalue` pipe can be used, but unfortunately it sorts by key. Maps already have an order and it would be great to be able to keep it!

We can define out own pipe `mapkeyvalue` which preserves the order of items in the map:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

// Holds a weak reference to its key (here a map), so if it is no longer referenced its value can be garbage collected.
const cache = new WeakMap<ReadonlyMap<any, any>, Array<{ key: any; value: any }>>();

@Pipe({ name: 'mapkeyvalue', pure: true })
export class MapKeyValuePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<K, V>(input: ReadonlyMap<K, V>): Iterable<{ key: K; value: V }> {
    const existing = cache.get(input);
    if (existing !== undefined) {
      return existing;
    }

    const iterable = Array.from(input, ([key, value]) => ({ key, value }));
    cache.set(input, iterable);
    return iterable;
  }
}
```

It can be used like so:

```html
<mat-select>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let choice of choicesMap | mapkeyvalue" [value]="choice.key">
    {{ choice.value }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

As people have mentioned in the comments keyvalue pipe does not retain the order of insertion (which is the primary purpose of Map).

Anyhow, looks like if you have a Map object and want to preserve the order, the cleanest way to do so is entries() function:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of map.entries()">
        <span>key: {{item[0]}}</span>
        <span>value: {{item[1]}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31420#issuecomment-635377113 why you should avoid using .entries()

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Florian , this saved me hours of debugging

Comment: NOT USE IT - you will get `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`