# ngFor map object

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor

I have some difficulties to understand how the ngFor works with map.

So this is my HTML code:

```
<div *ngFor="let country of wars.getCountrys()">
```

and here my TypeScript code:

```
wars: Map < number, Array < country> > = new Map < number, Array < country > > ();

getCountrys() {
    console.log('getCountrys()');
    return Array.from(this.wars.keys());
}
```

Everything is working good, however in the console I have 2 `getCountrys()` I don't understand why the function `getCountrys()` is called 2 times.

Comment: [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187362/how-to-iterate-using-ngfor-loop-map-containing-key-as-string-and-values-as-map-i)

Comment: This may have to do with Angular's dev mode additional change detection check. Is it logged twice in production mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Angular, there is something called **ChangeDetection**
its basically to detect when component data changes, and then automatically re-render the view to reflect that change.

in the Development mode in the angular application there is an additional cycle of detection is done, which means now we have two detection cycles.

these two cycles results executing your method twice.

Comment: could you provide a link to documentation on this?

Comment: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the function to generate the array. Create it inside the constructor as a variable.

In constructor:

```
this.countries = Array.from(this.wars.keys());
```

In html:

```
<div *ngFor="let country of countries">
```