# Don't sort the Map when using ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using ngFor to display a Map. To do so, I am using the keyvalue. It looks like this:

```
*ngFor="let upgrade of upgrades | keyvalue"
```

My Problem now is, that [keyvalue](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) sorts my Map. I don't want this and don't know how to stop the sorting.

I tried using `sortOrder = (a): number => {return (a)};` as compareFn; it worked, but I don't think that this is the corret way of doing it?

Comment: This might be sidetracking, but, what is wrong with actually sorting the info? Usually that makes it nicer for the end user's view :)

Answer (score 0):

since you are working with Map, If you do not want to sort the key
you can use

```
*ngFor="let key of upgrades.keys()"
```

or

```
 *ngFor="let entry of upgrades.entries()"
```

if you still want to use keyvalue pipe, your way is the right way. although it's a little confusing.
Since compareFn return a number, your sortOrder function will probably understand as null or NaN. I prefer `(a,b)=>1`  to be more clear. But it does not matter, the sorting is still happening, and probably waste some CPU time.

Comment: I did actually see that attempt  here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187362/how-to-iterate-using-ngfor-loop-map-containing-key-as-string-and-values-as-map-i). But, as mentioned there, this doesn't work.

Comment: Surprised to see that does not work, but good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `keyvalue` pipe does sort by the keys. I suspect this was a requirement for `ngClass` and `ngStyle`, because this was mentioned in the source code comments.

You can't stop the sorting. I'd just create my own pipe.

```
@Pipe({name: 'entries', pure: true})
export class EntriesPipe implements PipeTransform {
     transform(value: May<any,any>) {
         return Array.from(value.entries());
     }
}
```

I made the pipe pure, but that's up to you. It's difficult to work with `Map<>` types if it's pure.

Comment: Sidenote: although this will work, you will lose some of the optimizations that the keyvalue pipe has https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.2.8/packages/common/src/pipes/keyvalue_pipe.ts#L25-L88