# angular 5 - The pipe 'keyvalue' could not be found

Tags: angular

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'keyvalue' could not be found ("

```
                 {{optionsData}}  <span  *ngFor="let [ERROR ->]item of postDetail.poll.votes | keyvalue">rgeeehr</span>

                </div"): ng:///NewPostModule/CommentComponent.html@87:57
```

Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'keyvalue' could not be found ("

```
                 {{optionsData}}  <span  *ngFor="let [ERROR ->]item of postDetail.poll.votes | keyvalue">rgeeehr</span>

                </div"): ng:///NewPostModule/CommentComponent.html@87:57
```

Comment: Did you import CommonModule in the component module?

Comment: yes already import CommonModule in the component module

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: Angular: 5.2.11

Comment: Did you try restarting ng serve?

Comment: many time restart but give same error

Comment: It only exists from angular 6.1. You can define your own pipe if upgrading angular is not an option : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49772435/1160794